# How to do the shortcut function in ECC when N (Private Key) is Known

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, public-key

When N or private key is known, we don't have to iterate through all the process just to get the final location given the two initial points. How is that shortcut function implemented given the equation, two initial points and N?

For example:

```
Equation : y^2 = x^3 - 4x + 1
Initial Points : 

A = (2, 1)

B = (-2, -1)


N = 1024 iterations
```

How will I get the Final Point Location using the shortcut function in ECC, without getting through the process from start to finish just to find the Final location?

Comment: Lookup double-and-add algorithm for elliptic curve. It is O(log(N))

Comment: Thanks @JamesKPolk